# Wiener processes probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Calculate $\mathbb{P}((\sqrt{3}-1)W_1+W_2 > 0 | W_1 > 0)$
> where $W_t$ is a Wiener process

---

My attempt:
$$
\mathbb{P}((\sqrt{3}-1)W_1+W_2 > 0 | W_1 > 0) = \\
\frac{\mathbb{P}((\sqrt{3}-1)W_1+W_2 > 0, W_1 > 0)}{\mathbb{P}(W_1 > 0)} = \\
\frac{\mathbb{P}((\sqrt{3}W_1+W_2-W_1 > 0, W_1 > 0)}{\mathbb{P}(W_1 > 0)} = \\
\frac{\mathbb{P}((W_3+W_2-W_1 > 0, W_1 > 0)}{\mathbb{P}(W_1 > 0)} = \\
\frac{\mathbb{P}((W_3-W_2+2(W_2-W_1)+W_1 - W_0 > 0, W_1 - W_0 > 0)}{\frac{1}{2}} = \\
2\mathbb{P}((W_3-W_2+2(W_2-W_1)+W_1 - W_0 > 0, W_1 - W_0 > 0) = 
$$
here I got stuck. How do I process further? I see that $W_3-W_2$ is $N(0,1)$, $2(W_2-W_1)$ is $N(0,4)$ and $W_1-W_0$ is $N(0,1)$ but I dont know how to deal with $W_1-W_0>0$.

I am also not sure if $\sqrt{3}W_1 = W_3$. I know that if we had $\sqrt{3}(W_1-W_0)$ it would be $N(0, \sqrt{3}^2\cdot1) = N(0,3)$

Comment: "I am also not sure if $\sqrt{3}W_1 = W_3$" they're not equal (there is equality just in distribution; you could still plug it in there if the same were true for its joint distribution with $(W_1,W_2)$, which is not the case). To answer your question, note that in the denominator you have $\mathrm{P} ((X_1,X_2) \in A)$, where $(X_1,X_2)$ is a centered Gaussian vector, and $A$ is some angle placed at origin. Transform this to $\mathrm{P} ((Z_1,Z_2) \in B)$, where $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is a *standard* Gaussian vector, and use the fact that its polar angle is uniformly distributed.